# How to read SAP Cloud Platform User-Provided Variables from a SAPUI5 app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I was looking for a way to read the User-Provided Variables using JavaScript from a SAPUI5 app.
I've seen examples for node.js and Java, but those don't apply to a SAPUI5 app.

The node.js "version" requires a `@sap/xsenv` package that unfortunately I don't seem to be able to include in my app.

I'd like to read those variables from a SAPUI5 controller.

Has anyone done that before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an action on your backend application.
And this action needs to read environment variables from directly app or via using [CF API](https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.106.0/index.html#get-environment-variables-for-an-app) and must return that to you as response.

You should not read directly anything using CF credentials in a frontend application.